# hotkey to switch application

Tags: macos, keyboard

I am running os 10.8.4 and would like to switch between full screen applications that are already open using hotkeys. I can only use cmd + 1 to move to space 1, but cmd + 2 does not work if you have windows maximized. This is a know limitation. Is there a third party app that I can get that can do this? (I have tried witch, alfred & QS). I am not looking for shortcuts to open a new app - I want to switch between apps that are already open.

I have chrome, iterm2 & remote desktop that I use all the time. I'd like assign a hotkey to each of these 3 apps, and would like to switch to any of them with a hot key.

I was able to do this in 10.6, and this is the one single feature that they got rid of on 10.8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[TotalSpaces](http://totalspaces.binaryage.com), running on 10.8.4, allows me to switch between full screen apps using the three-finger swipe on the trackpad, and allows me to assign specific apps to their own desktops. I haven't found a better app for my workflow, which allows me to switch between 7-8 specific desktops every session.

Comment: Hi Dave, I installed totalspaces. I have two four desktops and 2 full screen apps. I can switch to windows using hotkeys, but not to the fullscreen apps. Can you confirm this behaviour?

Comment: @Trewq, that depends on how you configure it. I actually use the trackpad to change quickly from desktop to full screen apps and vice versa. All of my full-screen desktops are on the right side, and my regular desktops are on the left. If I need to go quickly from one to six, for example, I swipe up with three fingers and click the desktop from the selection that appears along the top of the screen. It makes it simple to toggle from desktop to desktop.

Comment: Also, by default, you can use SHIFT-CTRL-SPACE to go to a primary screen where all of your desktops will appear on the screen in the center, and the fullscreen apps will be along the bottom. With all of the desktops I use, this app simplifies things for me greatly.

Comment: To your point though, if you're trying to assign Hotkeys to spaces in the Layout view, it does appear that you can only do so with non-full screen desktops.