# Hotkey to switch to Google Chrome and go to the omnibox (location bar)

Tags: keyboard, applescript, shortcut, script, karabiner

I would like to setup a keyboard shortcut/hotkey that would switch to Google Chrome and go to the omnibox (address bar).  I intend to use it invoke various custom search engines.

I found a couple of related questions but not quite there:

- [hotkey to switch application](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/100019/hotkey-to-switch-application) -- TotalSpaces -- requires a trackpad, which I don't use -- my daily driver is the keyboard.
- [Script to raise a single window to the front](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/39204/script-to-raise-a-single-window-to-the-front) -- I don't know how bind an AppleScript script to a hotkey (I'm new to the Mac).

I had done something like this with AutoHotKey on Windows.  What's the right tool on the Mac?

I am already using Karabiner-Elements and Alfred.

Comment: I found https://karabiner-elements.pqrs.org/docs/json/typical-complex-modifications-examples/#open-alfred-4-if-escape-is-held-down and set up a hotkey to switch to Google Chrome.  However, I'm missing the last step -- how to put the cursor into the Address Bar.

Comment: Most browsers use Cmd/L

Comment: Yes -- can I have Karabiner send Cmd/L to the browser for me?

Comment: You could add `activate "Google Chrome"` to the head of the raise script, & `keystroke "l" with command down` to the end, then all you need do is add a keystroke for the whole thing saved as a Service. No 3rd party app required.

Comment: Thank you! Is https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/39204/script-to-raise-a-single-window-to-the-front the raise script?  How do I save the thing as a Service?  (Total noob question.)  In the meantime, I found if I use `open -n -a 'Google Chrome.app'` in Karabiner, I get the desired effect as well.

Comment: `open -n -a ...` is a little slow though... takes longer to launch a new instance of Chrome than to open the current instance. =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your task is ill-defined & what you have found so far overkill - (that this is because you are new to Mac means that's nothing to be ashamed of, we all start somewhere;) If all you need is to bring an app to the front & enable the location area you can do it in Applescript in 2 lines.

```
tell application "Google Chrome" to activate
tell application "System Events" to keystroke "l" using command down
```

perhaps with an optional `delay 0.5` in between those lines in case it's a bit slow to come to the front.

The only difficulty is to make this key-commandable.

If you set this up as a Script event in Automator, then in previous OSes [I think up to Mojave, I haven't used anything newer] you could just define it as a Service. Once defined & saved, you can then call the Service using
System Prefs > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Services
I think this has changed since Catalina, but someone else would need to detail precisely how.
So long as you give it a shortcut that doesn't conflict with anything else, then simply hitting that shortcut will bring Chrome to the front [or launch it if it's not already running] & set the cursor into the search/location bar. It will do this on the current tab if one is already open, or make a new window if nothing was open.

Comment: Yay! Thank you, thank you, thank you @Tetsujin!  That did it.  Just like you said.  Here is a link to the documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/MacAutomationScriptingGuide/MakeaSystem-WideService.html  This worked on Catalina.

Comment: Glad you got it. I wasn't certain the Automator method was still valid after Mojave. Glad it worked:)